# using data from database in HTML not working

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and i need to get informations from a database table and use them in the HTML code, I've did it once and it works, and now i am trying the same thing with another page and its not working, maybe i've missed something.

Here's my route:

```
Route::get('/servicedetails{id}', function($id) {

    $services = DB::table('services')->where('id','=', $id)->get();

    return view('service_details')->with('services', $services);
});
```

And here's my HTML:

```
@foreach ($services as $service)

            <div class="container">
                <h3 style="margin-left:45%; font-size:40px;">{{$service['id']}}</h3>
                <img src="images/portfolio/full/item11.png" style="border-radius:50px; padding-top:20px; float:left;">
                <p style="float:left; margin-top:15%; margin-left:50px;">Description goes here</p>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

if I put in my route : return $services i get the service with the id needed
but when i do this its not working

Comment: What does it mean "it's not working"?

Comment: I am getting this error: Undefined variable: service (View: C:\wamp\www\project\resources\views\service_details.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

The query response is an object.  In order to access object elements use this

```
   {{$service->id}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last remark, I'm guessing you have to remove the @foreach. You seem to be returning a single object and not a collection. (which is why `$service` wasn't found - your single service doesn't contain another one, it contains the attributes)

Apart from that it returns an object, not an array, so you have to access the id like this: `$services->id`

Try this code:

```
 <div class="container">
            <h3 style="margin-left:45%; font-size:40px;">{{ $services->id }}</h3>
            <img src="images/portfolio/full/item11.png" style="border-radius:50px; padding-top:20px; float:left;">
            <p style="float:left; margin-top:15%; margin-left:50px;">Description goes here</p>
 </div>
```